# Magento2: what is the best way to detect mobile device?

Tags: magento2, mobile-device

I have used below code to detect mobile in magento1.

```
$isMobile = Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match(
    Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(),
    $_SERVER
);
```

I am not sure if there is something available for Magento2 as well. Anyone have used something like this in magento2?

Comment: To detect the client devices, we have an extension here https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-mobiledetect

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue?

Comment: You should approve answer or ask your queries to help other developers to find right solutions.

Comment: @VishwasSoni I've tried you solution its give me blank page. without any error. That's why i've not accepted yet.

Comment: @Kul Debug the issue and came back with the errors you get. A community will help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best way is to detect a mobile device is

```
//Identifying if user is on mobile browser or not
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4))) {
    $browserStatus = 'Mobile';
}
```

I have used this in many websites and working perfect.

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 7):

You can use same class in Magento2.

```
protected $httpHeader;

protected $mobileAgent;

public function __construct(
   ...
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader,
    \Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile $mobileAgent
   ...
) {
    $this->httpHeader = $httpHeader;
    $this->mobileAgent = $mobileAgent
}

public function isMobile(){
  $userAgent = $this->httpHeader->getHttpUserAgent();

  return $this->mobileAgent->match($userAgent, $_SERVER); //the code which you want.
}
```

Comment: Getting Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: http_user_agent in /var/www/Magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/UserAgent/Features/Adapter/Browscap.php on line 69 exception.... please help me

Comment: @kranthi you might have to build your plugin after DI injection `php bin\magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: @SumitKumar ran command but no use

Comment: It seems your browser is not set http_user_agent. Try to use if condition like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130830/php-undefined-index-http-user-agent

Comment: I am also getting the same error - Undefined index: http_user_agent in /var/www/Magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/UserAgent/Features/Adapter/Browscap.php on line 69 exception

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code

```
   protected $httpHeader;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader,
    )
    {
         $this->httpHeader = $httpHeader;
         parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute(){
      $userAgent = $this->httpHeader->getHttpUserAgent();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You use this Library for Mobile Detect

[Link](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)

create custom module add library in module and create helper and put this function to global use.

```
  public function isMobile() 
  {
     return $this->mobileDetector->isMobile() || $this->mobileDetector->isTablet();
  }
```

Add mobileDetector in your constructor to inject library.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject only one class "\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header", because "\Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match" is a static method, so this will work:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header
 */
protected $httpHeader;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader
) {
    $this->httpHeader = $httpHeader;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isMobile()
{
    $userAgent = $this->httpHeader->getHttpUserAgent();
    return \Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match($userAgent, $_SERVER);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Magento 2.3.2

I found that the easiest way is to add ["Mobile_Detect.php"](http://mobiledetect.net/) to the "magento_path/lib/internal" folder. Then call it into my .phtml template file using the following:

```
<?php 
include(BP.'/lib/internal/Mobile_Detect.php');
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){
    echo "Is Mobile";
} else{
    echo "Is Desktop";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps someone.