# Magento2.1 different mobile view

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, catalogsearch, list.phtml, mobile-device

I want to see search results in list mode by default in **desktop**, and see it on grid mode on **mobile**.
What should I do? 
Right now I edited *catalog search* `list.phtml` to show list mode by default on search result page but on mobile, I see list mode too. I want to see grid mode on **mobile**.

**Update from comment:**

```
if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
    $viewMode = 'list';
    $image = 'category_page_list';
    $showDescription = false;
    $templateType = 
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
} else {
    $viewMode = 'grid';
    $image = 'category_page_grid';
    $showDescription = true;
    $templateType = 
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
}
```

but it works on any device, can not seperate them for devices

Comment: Can you share the code efforts you have made till now?

Comment: if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $image = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }   but it works on any device, can not seperate them for devices

Comment: You can refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/194051/2443 to check for mobile device

Comment: Thanks, good, but how can I create a global function for it? I mean don't use if.. just run the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://marketplace.magento.com/eadesignro-module-mobiledetect.html

Finally, got this extension, it works well.

Comment: its not working can you tell me how its working for you

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create a new theme having the parent as your current theme.
2. Then set up the new theme as an exception for the mobile devices.
3. In the new theme, you can override the list.phtml file and write your custom logic (or simply remove the code for the grid view. Keep the code for the list view only).

**Update: Add an exception for mobile devices**

1. Go to **Design** >> **Configuration** and click on the row of the currently applied theme.
2. Under **Design Rule** >> **User Agent Rules**, you will find **Add New User Agent Rule** button. Click on it to add the exception. Input the value of the Search String and select the theme as the exception.

Search strings are either normal strings or regular expressions (PCRE).

3. Save the configuration and deploy the static content.

[image: Theme Exception]

I hope it makes sense.

Please let me know if you have any related question.

Add "mobile" in search string and select any template you want to use for mobile, and its done. For all mobile devices automatically those templates will be taken.
[image: options]

Comment: Thanks... don't understand number2. how can i do it?

Comment: @PMPD, I have updated my answer.